# Apache POI XSLF replace image with another image

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I'm using Apache POI as a way to template out a layout with placeholder shapes I replace with contents I retrieve from a restful call.

All of this is working fine, but I can't find a way to replace an image with another image.

I know it is possible to create and add it to a slide using the following code:

```
int idx = ui.getPpt().addPicture(bytes, XSLFPictureData.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
XSLFPictureShape pic = slide.createPicture(idx);
```

This all works but what I'd like to do is replace an existing image but can't seem to find a way to do it as I can with tables and text objects.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First read the slide and get the shape which contains the picture.
The shape will be an instance of `XSLFPictureShape`.
Use the following code:

```
for(XSLFShape shape : slide.getShapes()) {

   XSLFPictureShape image = (XSLFPictureShape) shape;
   image.getPictureData().setData(IOUtils.toByteArray(new  FileInputStream("path_to_image"));

}
```